# XPath: how to extract nodes from a path containing an unknown tag name?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xpath

```
<html><body>
<div id="start">
   <div>
      <div>NOT A TARGET</div>
   </div>
   <aBcDeFG>
      <div>target</div>
   </aBcDeFG>
</div>
</body></html>
```

There is a document similar to this one. The `<aBcDeFG>` tag is a random tag generated on every page refresh. I wrote an XPath expression with wildcard to locate the `target` `div`:

```
$x('/html/body/div/*/div')
```

The expression returns two `div`s, as `NOT A TARGET` is matched: `[div, div]`.

`$x('/html/body/div/*[2]/div')` doesn't work, the return value is empty.

`$x('/html/body/div/node()[2]/div')` doesn't work either, the return value is empty.

How can I locate an unknown tag just by its index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `/html/body/div/*[2]/div` selector [is correct](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/1149f5afe9fefd050793fe1cb831ad7e). I guess you have difficulties fetching the node in the developer tools console. Try this:

```
$x('/html/body/div/*[2]/div')[0].innerHTML
```

**Example using `document.evaluate`**

```js
var r = document.evaluate('/html/body/div/*[2]/div', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
var n = r.iterateNext();
console.log(n.innerHTML);
```

```html
<html><body>
<div id="start">
   <div>
      <div>NOT A TARGET</div>
   </div>
   <aBcDeFG>
      <div>target</div>
   </aBcDeFG>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: `[position() = 2]` is the same thing as `[2]`.

Comment: Thanks, I was confused at a `[2]` thing at that time. But now I'm clear.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
'(/html/body/div/*[2])/div'
```

Answer (score 0):

If when syou say "an unknown" tag, you mean "a tag different from DIV", you could use this xpath:

```
/html/body/div/*[not(name(.)='div')]/div
```